# ServerSocket not accepting on droid emulator

Tags: java, android, eclipse, networking, serversocket

I'm trying to set up a basic network connection using the droid emulators with eclipse but I'm having problems. The server reaches the line "Socket s = ss.accept();" and waits for the client to connect, but the client can't seem to connect.

Now I've been able to have my client connect to a python server that I created and does the same thing as the server I made for the droid. I've allowed the Internet Uses on both client and server in the AndroidManifest so I'm at a lose as to why this server isn't working on my droid emulator.

Sever:

```
       ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(8888);
            while(!end){
                    Socket s = ss.accept();
                    Log.v("Server","Connection found");
                    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(),true); 
                    String st = input.readLine();
```

Client:

```
        Socket s = new Socket(MYIPADDR,8888);

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to Luka's answer since you're probably going to run into future issues:

If you're using sockets, you may want to use a library to help with all the maintenance that's really required for a stable connection.

A good library to use for handling the connection would be: https://github.com/koush/android-websockets

It'll keep the connection alive and is fairly simple to change around to fit your sending needs. The only thing it's missing is a callback feature to deal with incoming data, but that would be way easier to implement than entirely setting up something from scratch to deal with the whole connection.